# use 'messi' Jquery plugin in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-plugins, messagebox

I'm using 'messi' Jquery notification plugin , in Login.aspx , if user is not Registered then a message is shown to user and redirect him to Register.aspx:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "    <script>alert('this is a message');window.location.href='Register.aspx';</script>", true);
```

this code works fine and I should click on OK button then page will be redirected, but when I use `Messi.alert()` instead of `alert()` , the message appears just for a second and then redirection is done automatically.
I need to use this plugin what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use callback in this case. E.g. Define you function in your JavaScript code as:

```
function alertRedirect(message, url) {
  new Messi(message, {title: 'Warning', 
                      modal: true, 
                      buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'OK', val: 'OK'}],
                      callback: function() {
      location.href = url;
  }});
}
```

And call it in your .net Code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alertRedirect('this is a message','Register.aspx');", true);
```

Comment: Have u used the code as shown? You *should not* have redirection code `window.location.href='Register.aspx'` in your ASP.NET code anymore

Comment: would you explain please?I need expert`s guidance

Comment: If you put the code above as is (top part into JavaScript, bottom part *exaxtly as it is* into your C# code *replacing old line* - it should work. the function doesn't redirect right away, but only when alert is closed - via calling callback function

Comment: I did copy and paste your code snippet above and tried but still redirection is not as we expect .

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize - an explicit button is required for callback to work. I have updated JavaScript code - please try it again

Comment: I don`t realize too , what`s wrong with it . I replaced your code snippet again but...did you try on your own machine? was it OK?

Comment: Yes the latest version works fine. Here's live demo (without ASP.NET part of course): http://jsfiddle.net/3Hbtx/

Comment: I`m pretty surprised ! I don`t know what to do , may I`d better to find another Plugin . Maybe there's something wrong with my c# code, it seems js works fine.

Comment: Does it display the message but doesn't do redirect? Or even message is not displayed?

Comment: Something else is going on. Something else is doing the redirect. Check your code for all references to redirect URL

Comment: You are right but I don`t know what is that and how to catch it

Comment: Try to do a global search for `Register.aspx` and see where else in code it is mentioned.